# Retrieving features from QgsFieldExpressionWidget using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, fields-attributes, typeerror, qgsexpression

I'm working on a plugin for QGIS 3 and I'm fighting with the `QgsFieldExpressionWidget` widget.

I don't know how how to evaluate the expression added in the box and get the corresponding features as a Python list.

Within the plugin I would like to write a function to call that is able to know if in the `QgsFieldExpressionWidget` is a simple field (without expression) or a expression that has to be evaluated.

No problem for the first part, but API changed for the `QgsFieldExpression` and I'm not able to follow the instruction of the [PyQGIS cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html).

This is the function I'm trying to write:

```py
 def getFields(lay, exp):

    # vector layer from the combobox
    vl = lay.currentLayer()
    # vector field (or expression)
    field = exp.currentText()

    data = []

    # get the data from the layer
    # no expression
    if not exp.currentField()[1]:
        for i in vl.getFeatures():
            data.append(i[field])

    # if expression is selected

    # this is the piece of code that is not working for QGIS 3

    else:
        # expression name
        fil = exp.currentField()[0]
        # expr = QgsExpression(fil)
        # for i in vl.getFeatures():
            # data.append(expr.evaluate(i, vl.pendingFields()))
    
    return data
```

and this is the error I get:

> TypeError: QgsExpression.evaluate(): arguments did not match any
> overloaded call:   overload 1: too many arguments   overload 2:
> argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'

Comment: Which is the returned error?

Comment: This is the error: `TypeError: QgsExpression.evaluate(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: too many arguments
  overload 2: argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFeature'`

Comment: After a quick test, it seems to work using `evaluate()` without any argument inside. Can you confirm it?

Comment: I can confirm I don't have any error, but the `data` list is a list of `None` after the evaluation of the expression. BTW: `exp.isValid()` returns `True`

Comment: It is still unclear to me which operation you are doing. However, I reproduced your issue by creating a new field storing some simple expressions. Then, I looped over the features and used `expr = QgsExpression(str(i['field_name']))` and then `value = expr.evaluate()` (both inside the loop) and it printed the proper result (when there was an expression in the field). Maybe you need to convert the expression to a string before passing it?

Comment: sorry for the delay of the comment.. want I want to achieve is simple. Imagine a shapefile that has the float attribute **rain**. If I write the expression `'rain / 10'`, how can I have a list of the results of that field?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try the method posted in your [other question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244068/pyqgis-gives-typeerror-qgsexpression-prepare-argument-1-has-unexpected-type?noredirect=1&lq=1) using the [`QgsExpressionContext`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContext.html) and [`QgsExpressionContextScope`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextScope.html) classes:

```py
def getFields(lay, exp):
    vl = lay.currentLayer()
    field = exp.currentText()

    context = QgsExpressionContext()
    scope = QgsExpressionContextScope()
    data = []

    if not exp.currentField()[1]:
        for i in vl.getFeatures():
            data.append(i[field])
    else:
        fil = exp.currentField()[0]
        for i in vl.getFeatures():
            scope.setFeature(i)
            context.appendScope(scope)
            exp = QgsExpression(fil)
            data.append(exp.evaluate(context))

    return data
```