# PyQGIS gives TypeError: QgsExpression.prepare(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFields'?

Tags: pyqgis, typeerror, qgis-3

This question is very related to the unanswered [Retrieve features from QgsFieldExpressionWidget pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240004)

I have a layer and I've build a `QgsExpression` that involves a field of that layer. What I'm trying to do is to evaluate the expression and get the results as a single list.

The problem is that I'm trying to do this with QGIS master (so the future 3 version) and the instruction of the [PyQGIS cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#expressions-with-features) are outdated because some [API are changed](http://qgis.org/api/api_break.html#qgis_api_break_3_0_QgsExpression).

Just to have an example:

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
exp = QgsExpression('PH > 7') # where PH is the name of a field
exp.prepare(vl.pendingFields())


# then I get this error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: QgsExpression.prepare(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QgsFields'
```

Someone has already successfully used the `QgsExpression` for QGIS master?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

I used your code in my QGIS Python Console (with a shapefile with 'PH' field; only one value > 7) and I got a result (see next image).

[image]

So, I printed 'vl.pendingFields()' to find out what kind of object is:

```
>>>vl.pendingFields()
<qgis._core.QgsFields object at 0x17E10E40>
```

and afterward, a help for **QgsExpression.prepare** for corroborating wich parameters it uses:

```
help(QgsExpression.prepare)
Help on built-in function prepare:

prepare(...)
    QgsExpression.prepare(QgsFields) -> bool
    QgsExpression.prepare(QgsExpressionContext) -> bool
```

In my case, used parameter is correct and the result was as expected. So, I suggest that you use 'help' command with your QGIS future 3 version to find out the new kind of parameters to use.

Comment: HI. thanks for the answer. I think that the use of `prepare` is deprecated in QGIS 3. The help function return my: `prepare(...)
    Get the expression ready for evaluation - find out column indexes.
     \param context context for preparing expression
    .. versionadded:: 2.12
     :rtype: bool`

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS 3.0, you may need to use a combination of the [QgsExpressionContext](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContext.html) and [QgsExpressionContextScope](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsExpressionContextScope.html) classes:

```
vl = iface.activeLayer()
features = [feat for feat in vl.getFeatures()]

context = QgsExpressionContext()
scope = QgsExpressionContextScope()
context.appendScope(scope)
listOfResults = []

for feat in features:
    scope.setFeature(feat)
    exp = QgsExpression('PH > 7')
    listOfResults.append(exp.evaluate(context))
```

The output is boolean, either 0 (false) or 1 (true), and stored in a list:

```
>>> [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: `context.appendScope(scope)` line should be moved outside of the loop. Otherwise QGIS crashes.

Answer (score 2):

```
    for name, layer in layers.iteritems():
        if(layer.name()=="[layer name]"):

            lay=layer

    expr = QgsExpression("\"REFCAT\"=22162C50309009")

    expr = QgsExpression(expresion)
    selection= lay.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest(expr))
    ids = [s.id() for s in selection]
    lay.setSelectedFeatures(ids)
    iface.legendInterface().setCurrentLayer(lay)
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

Is a code used by me, try changing the format of the expression with double quotation marks.